# Can't show MBProgressHUD

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mbprogresshud

In [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service) said that using MBProgressHUD is easy.
But I can't make it.

Here my code:

```
- (IBAction)save{
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
    HUD.delegate = self;
    [HUD show:YES];

    NSString *title = [page stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
    SavePageAs *savePage = [[SavePageAs alloc] initWithUrl:self.site directory:title];
    [savePage save];
    [HUD hide:YES];
}
```

The progress indicator is not showing during `savePage save` method run, but shows after the page completely saved (the indicator is shown for less than 1 second).

I also tried this way:

```
- (IBAction)save {

    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
   [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];

   HUD.delegate = self;
   HUD.labelText = @"Saving...";

   [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(performFetchOnMainThread) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}

- (void) savingPage{
    NSString *title = [page stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
    SavePageAs *savePage = [[SavePageAs alloc] initWithUrl:self.site directory:title];
    [savePage save];
}

-(void) performFetchOnMainThread    {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(savingPage) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

But still no luck. Anyone let me know where I'm lack here?

P.S: `savePage save` is saving all website contents to local directory. I wish once the saving is complete the progressHUD disappear.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use `self.navigationController.view` to allocate and init `HUD`? You need to initialize it with the viewController's view for which you need to show it.

Comment: even i use self.view the result still same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try allocation of `HUD` on the `viewWillAppear:` instead of `-(IBAction)save` because sometimes allocation takes up the whole time and by the time it allocates whole task is finished.

Copy Following links to `viewWillAppear:` and remove them from `-(IBAction)save`

```
 HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
 [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];

 HUD.delegate = self;
 HUD.labelText = @"Saving...";
```

**EDIT:** Keep allocations on `viewWillAppear:` and change code as shown below:

```
- (IBAction)save {
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(showHUD) withObject:nil];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(savingPage) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}

- (void) savingPage{
    NSString *title = [page stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
    SavePageAs *savePage = [[SavePageAs alloc] initWithUrl:self.site directory:title];
    [savePage save];
    [HUD hide:YES];
}

-(void)showHUD {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   [HUD show:YES];
   [pool release];
}
```

What this will do is create a separate thread to display HUD as main thread is being engaged by savingPage method.

If this too doesn't work, then just change `waitUntilDone:YES` to `waitUntilDone:NO`

**Note:** As per [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000051-1722)

> Important If you use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), you cannot
>   use autorelease pools directly. Instead, you use @autoreleasepool
>   blocks instead. For example, in place of:
>
> ```
> NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init;
> // Code benefitting from a local autorelease pool.
> [pool release];
> ```
>
> you would write:
>
> ```
> @autoreleasepool {
>     // Code benefitting from a local autorelease pool.
> }
> ```
>
> @autoreleasepool blocks are more efficient than using an instance of
>   NSAutoreleasePool directly; you can also use them even if you do not
>   use ARC.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Parth, actually i've alloced the HUD in the viewWillAppear for show progress when my webview is loading. And then i have button to save the web contents in -(IBAction)save, here i want to make another progress bar. So, based on your advice i  only need to remove the alocation from -(IBAction)save method (coz i've already have in viewWillAppear:). That way, it still show the same result, progressHUD show after the page completely saved instead of during the save process. (and merely show less than 1 second)

Comment: @dejoong: I have edited my answer. Please check **EDIT** section of my answer.

Comment: @dejoong: Did the **EDIT** help you? I have made some changes few seconds ago

Comment: Great.., works like charm.
but i think you forgot to put toTarget:self into -> [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(showHUD) withObject:nil];
thanks for helping anyway

Comment: Hi Parth, little ask.., i got -> __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xb3039e0 of class __NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking on console. do u think its ok with "pool" things? or do i need to add more code here?

Comment: @dejoong: Check the `-(void)showHUD` method. I have made code modifications there to solve the warning `__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xb3039e0 of class __NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking on console` that you get. I hope this should work great now. Glad, I could help you.

Comment: @dejoong: I have added `NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];` and `[pool release];` lines around `[HUD show:YES];`. Check the **Note** section if you are using ARC.

Answer (score 2):

check out this code

```
- (IBAction)save{
        HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
        HUD.graceTime     = .1;
        HUD.navigationBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
        HUD.labelText     = @"Saving";
        HUD.delegate      = self;
        [self.view addSubview:HUD];

         [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(savingPage) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
    }


    - (void) savingPage{
        NSString *title = [page stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
        SavePageAs *savePage = [[SavePageAs alloc] initWithUrl:self.site directory:title];
        [savePage save];
    }
```

when saveingpage method will be completed MBProgressHUD delegate will be called so implement this delegate method in your class,This will remove HUD from your view

```
 -(void)hudWasHidden
    {
        [HUD removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Comment: Hi Piyush, its crashing when im not using performFetchOnMainThread and HUD.navigationBar is not exist in my HUD class (Version 0.5). Anyway, i tried still use performFetchOnMainThread with your way, still show the same result.

Comment: The problem is that you are using performSelectorOnMainThread method which calls the savingPage method on main thread (not on background thread) due to this HUD does not show until savingPage method is finished and shows only for a sec just after savingPage method is finished, so try to run savingPage method on background thread instead of main thread.

Comment: yeah.. tat definitely make sense. but do you have idea how i prevent this error --> bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x5b04fb0: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
That was happened when i didnt use performSelectorOnMainThread

Comment: can you tell me in detail what does SavePageAs class do,may be you could show some code of that class,Does this class contains some ui related code ?

Comment: Thanks for helpin Piyush, as you said i merely put the HUD stuff inside another thread so as Parth solution i only need to put it in [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(showHUD) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

Comment: [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(savingPage) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES]; is what helped me the most! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the HUD allocation lines to

```
HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo: self.navigationcontroller.view animated:YES];
HUD.labelText....
```

And then in your saving method you can have

```
[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.navigationcontroller.view animated:NO];
```

Comment: hi tams, i put 2 method of showing the progressHUD, which one did u respond to? anyway, i tried both but no luck